# Breaking when a particular input is entered

Tags: python, loops

```
values = []
while True:
   values.append(int(input('Enter a value:')))
   if values.append(int(input('Enter a value:'))) == 0:
      break
```

I'm trying to exit the code when an input of 0 is entered. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Each time you call `input` a new `input` is being entered, and `list.append` will add the input to the list and return `None`, which is not equal to `0`.

You can use a variable `val` to store the input, and use it to test, if you want to store the value `0` in the list, append it before checking:

```
values = []
while True:
   val = int(input('Enter a value:'))
   values.append(val)  #  this will add `0` to the list when it's entered
   if val == 0:
      break
```

If you don't want to store it, append it after the if:

```
values = []
while True:
   val = int(input('Enter a value:'))
   if val == 0:
      break
   values.append(val)  #  this won't add `0` to the list when it's entered
```

Answer (score 0):

The return of `values.append(...)` is `None`. It only updates the variable. 
This means your code is always checking `None == 0` and will never exit.

```
a = values.append(int(input('Enter a value:')))
>> Enter a value:0
print(a) 
>> None 
print(values) 
>> [0]
```

A fix to you code would be:

```
values = []
while True:
    values.append(int(input('Enter a value:')))
    if values[-1] == 0:
        break
```

for `values[-1]`, using index `-1` is how you get the last value in the list. It's the same as `len(values) - 1`